# Update open-vm-tools

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, package-management, oracle-linux, vmware-tools

As per vulnerability [CVE-2022-31676](https://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/VMSA-2022-0024.html) I'm trying to update my Oracle Linux 8.6 systems open-vm-tools to 12.1.0. However, I'm finding that this package isn't still in the repository, so I have been trying to locate it in another RHEL-based repositories.

Finally, I found it in [centOS 9 appstream mirror](http://mirror.stream.centos.org/9-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/) but when I proceed with the installation I receive the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.33)(64bit) is needed by open-vm-tools-12.1.0-1.eln121.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) is needed by open-vm-tools-12.1.0-1.eln121.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.3()(64bit) is needed by open-vm-tools-12.1.0-1.eln121.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.3(OPENSSL_3.0.0)(64bit) is needed by open-vm-tools-12.1.0-1.eln121.x86_64
        libssl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by open-vm-tools-12.1.0-1.eln121.x86_64
        libssl.so.3(OPENSSL_3.0.0)(64bit) is needed by open-vm-tools-12.1.0-1.eln121.x86_64
```

Why this package isn't still in the OL86 repository? As it contains a vulnerability patch should be published as soon as possible.

Is there something I'm missing with this installation? Should I install using another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily really need to update to 12.1.0.

According to the [Oracle Errata](https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-6357.html) the CVE-2022-31676 is fixed in the package version:

- 11.3.5-1.el8_6.1

If you already are on that version you are safe.